# ASP.NET My Music Store

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need help Sir, newbie in MVC, I would like to ask why I can't find
the store DB even it is  declared at the bottom.

The "storeDB" does not exist in the current context

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using MyMusicStore.Models;

    namespace MyMusicStore.Controllers
    {
        public class StoreController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Store/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();
                return View(genres);
            }

            public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
            {
                var newGenre = new Genre { Name = genre };
                return View (newGenre);
            }

            public ActionResult Details(int id)
            {
                var album = new Album { Title = "Album" + id };
                return View(album);
            }

            public class StoreController : Controller
            {
                MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside of the class StoreController, you declare StoreController a second time, and declare the variable inside that. What you've made is what's called an 'inner class', and the inner class is DIFFERENT from the outer class even though it appears to have the same name, it is brand new.

So you meant to do this instead:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyMusicStore.Models;

namespace MyMusicStore.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Store/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();
            return View(genres);
        }

        public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
        {
            var newGenre = new Genre { Name = genre };
            return View (newGenre);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var album = new Album { Title = "Album" + id };
            return View(album);
        }

        MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();


    }
}
```